# How typescript requier Nodejs module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

i read many similar question

this is the workaround i am trying now

for example to mysql module in Nodejs

1.
cmd enter:

```
npm install typescript
npm install mysql
```

2. 

typescript write:

```
import * as ms from "mysql";
// i see some people write " import ms = require("mysql"); ", but i get the error
```

then i check console window in chrome devtool

i see error " Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined "

and this error seems to stop script from keep running.

Comment: 1. You can't use this module in the browser. 2. If you want to use modules in the browser you have to use type module.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski how can i do , i dont know these concepts.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript will, by default, transpile to JavasScript files using the CommonJS module format which browsers do not support.

You can [configure it to use ECMAScript modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) (which are [supported by browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html)).

However, the [mysql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) depends on APIs that are available in Node.js but not in web browsers so you **cannot** use it in a web browser.

You could write a web service (e.g. using [Express](https://expressjs.com/) hosted by Node.js) which accesses the database and then interact with it from the browser using forms, Ajax or Web Sockets.

Comment: maybe i understand , i need use http request  to get file from server ,
not open file from chrome ?

Comment: @Kaosu-Niku If you want to get a file, text or something from backend, you have to create an API Backend. You cannot get that direct. You have to send a request to created API backend and get from the backend. This question is very generally, you should use step by step because there are a lot of subjects that have to tell you. If you create step by step, it will be more better for you.